# What are the light emissions from an ion engine?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, plasma-physics, rocket-science, propulsion, ions

Consider an ion thruster like a DS4G (Dual-Stage 4 Grid) thruster. Gas is released, ionized, and accelerated. Assume it's in a vacuum, be it a chamber or space. Also assume the propellant is Xenon.

What emissions does the plasma give off as it leaves the grid? For sure the plasma will deionize, so peaks along emission bands make sense. Thermal emissions, too, since it's hot (per some definition, though I admittedly know little about plasma except ions and electrons can have very different 'temperatures') and there is a magnetic field confining the plasma until it breaks away instead of looping back to the rest of the spacecraft.

If I had instruments pointed at this - or a telescope - what would I see? What percent of the emissions are what? I'm assuming you'd mostly see the heat from the ion thruster itself (or the probe itself) and an emission band that would give away what gas it uses, but I'm not sure what else.